# How to set data to resize depending on columns and vise versa inside datagridview using C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sizing

I have one problem. When ever I try to print my datagridview it always splits in half, so what I wanna do is to find a way to set length of column name adapt to data inside the column or to set that data adapts to column name. Its not the best explanation but take a look at the pictures:

This is what I have now:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

So basically I want the name of the column and data inside the rows to be visible but to take as minimum space as they can, depending on what length is bigger, If column name is bigger, adapt to that, if data length is bigger, adapt to that. Any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following property:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

See here the documentation for [DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx) member `AllCells`:

> The column widths adjust to fit the contents of all cells in the
>   columns, including header cells.